# Lookup Table Errors

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I created a DataFrame for conforming mortgage limits by year and unit type.

```
year    one_unit    two_unit    three_unit  four_unit   seconds
1999    240000      307100       371200      461350     120000
2000    252700      323400       390900      485800     126350
2001    275000      351950       425400      528700     137500
2002    300700      384900       465200      578150     150350
2003    322700      413100       499300      620500     161350
2004    333700      427150       516300      641650     166850
2005    359650      460400       556500      691600     179825
2006    417000      533850       645300      801950     208500
2007    417000      533850       645300      801950     208500
```

Imported using the following code:

```
conform1999to2007_df = pd.read_csv("C:/conform1999to2007.csv", dtype=int, index_col='year')
```

However, when I attempt to perform a lookup:

```
conform1999to2007_df.lookup(1999,'one_unit')
```

or

```
conform1999to2007_df.lookup('1999','one_unit')
```

I get the following error messages, respectively:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-145-3acef6361d09>", line 1, in <module>
conform1999to2007_df.lookup(1999,'one_unit')

File "/data/unixhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2431, in lookup
n = len(row_labels)

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-146-51bdd8eebaab>", line 1, in <module>
conform1999to2007_df.lookup('1999','one_unit')

File "/data/unixhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2433, in lookup
raise ValueError('Row labels must have same size as column labels')

ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

I am hoping to get the value "240000".  I know this may be a trivial question but any assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need .get_value instead of .lookup

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

> DataFrame.**lookup**(*row_labels*, *col_labels*)
>
> ---
>
> Akin to:
>
> ```
> result = []
> for row, col in zip(row_labels, col_labels):
>      result.append(df.get_value(row, col))
> ```

In first argument you should pass row_labels, i.e. index. You should have your `year` column as index or you could do that with `set_index('year')`:

```
df = df.set_index('year')
```

In `lookup` method you passing your labels to `zip` function and they should be iterable. You could do that if you'll pass `list` or `tuple`.

```
In [142]: df.lookup((1999,), ('one_unit',))
Out[142]: array([240000])

In [143]: df.lookup([1999], ['one_unit'])
Out[143]: array([240000])
```

Btw, if you just need to find value in column `one_unit` with `year` column equals to 1999 you could do following (if your `year` column isn't an index):

```
In [152]: df[df.year==1999].one_unit
Out[152]: 
0    240000
Name: one_unit, dtype: int64
```